# Pycurl Error : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Curl'

Tags: python, pycurl

Brand new raspberry pi using the debian image from the pi site.

I used sudo apt-get install python-pycurl

My script looks like this

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1)
c.setopt(c.CAINFO, '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt')
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://theurl.com')
c.setopt(c.USERPWD, 'user:pass')
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, 'Field1=This&Field2=That')
c.perform()
```

I'm getting this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycurl.py", line 1, in <module>
import pycurl
  File "/home/pi/test/pycurl.py", line 3, in <module>
    c = pycurl.Curl()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Curl'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the path in the traceback.  It looks like you may be importing your own module called `pycurl.py`, not the actual pycurl library.  Try renaming that file to something else so Python imports the real pycurl.

Comment: You are right.  I changed the filename and now I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: No module named pycurl

Comment: @user1617655: Then I guess you haven't installed pycurl correctly.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  You were right on both accounts, the filename and pycurl config.  I changed default python version to 2.7 using     `sudo update-alternatives --config python` and it started working.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

python first checks in the current directory for a module, then in the python directory.
rename your file to `mypicurl.py` or something. otherwise, you're just importing the script.

edit: i just saw your comment, and this means you havn't installed it properly. try a reinstall or install from a .deb